# Node w/ Mysql: How do I insert a row value and a nested array at the same time?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, fetch

I have a node server posting data requests to a mysql database up and running. I am trying to figure out how to post a row of data that includes one column data type JSON with the purpose of inserting a nested array. How can I achieve this concept in one statement if possible? Below I have snippets of code that should cover the scope of this request:

**Array (from React state)**

```
menuItems: [
                {
                    "id": 1234,
                    "item_name": 'burger',
                    "category_id": 'meal',sauce',
                    "condiments": [{ id: 1, value: "ketchup sauce", isChecked: false },{ id: 2, value: "hot sauce", isChecked: false }],
                    "price": 6
                },
                {
                    "id": 1235,
                    "item_name": 'hot dog',
                    "category_id": 'meal',
                    "condiments": [{ id: 1, value: "ketchup sauce", isChecked: false },{ id: 2, value: "hot sauce", isChecked: false }],
                    "price": 6
                }
            ],
```

**Node**

```
app.post('/addMenuItem',  cors(), (req, res) => {
    
      //ASSUMING values are coming in from a request
      var values = {
        id: req.query.id,
        item_name: req.query.item_name,
        category_id: req.query.category_id,
        condiments: req.query.condiments,
        price: req.query.price,
       }

    
       //TYPICALLY I DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS BUT NOT SURE HOW TO HANDLE THE NEST
       var sql = 'INSERT INTO menu_item SET ?';


       // now the createStudent is an object you can use in your database insert logic.
       pool.query(sql, function (err, results) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
            return res.send(err)
            
        } else {
            console.log(results)
            return res.json({
                data: results
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: When using databases in Node it really helps to use promise-driven drivers like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/).

Comment: Tip: Expand that statement to a full `SET x=?, y=?, ...` and then prepare it. Run the prepared statement once for each entry in `menuItems `.

Comment: If this is a case of inserting one record, and then multiple others via a *one-to-many* association the same principle applies. You just iterate over the nested array instead.

Comment: It's really hard to give you a straight answer without knowing the definition of your table or tables. Why? recent Mysql versions have columns with JSON data types. Please [edit] your question to show us what your sample data will look like when stored in database rows.